# How to get one object property when the object is inside a array?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

Im developing a **Angular 8** app and i have to show in a table the registered users at the moment. I'm using `ng2-smart-table` to show the users but i have a problem: the response from backend is an array, obviously, but each array has an object and i need to get the property (the name in this case) of each one.

Here is the code i have:

```
  this.mainService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  this.users = res;
  this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.users);
```

The format of `res` is an array of the following:

```
{
_id: "5e5688bd1ef392001775c8c5"
nombre: "NICOLAS"
apellido: "SANABRIA"
email: "nico@ex.co"
nivel: 1
cargo: "Gerente EAP"
password: "$2a$10$jvqdJnIRKC4C9b5oSdmguOZA.UqqV.B7BnN1RhoMelFUk750K5BBW"
empresa: {_id: "5e5688bc1ef392001775c8c4", nombre: "P4", tipo: "EAP", estado: "pendiente", createdAt: "2020-02-26T15:03:24.638Z", …}
estado: "pendiente"
createdAt: "2020-02-26T15:03:25.067Z"
}
```

The object i need the property is "empresa"

I appreciate the help

Comment: `res[index].empresa`? where `index` comes from a for-loop/forEach

Comment: You want an array of emprasa properties?

Comment: I mean, the ng2-smart-table automatically sets the data in the respective columns, but when i asign the "empresa" data, i don't want to assign the object, but the name, and name is a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `valuePrepareFunction` and `filterFunction` in order to display the properties you want and still keep filtering capabilities.

I have created a quick [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-smart-table-object-property?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

The only changes are in your column definition, something like this:

```js
  settings = {
    columns: {
      // other columns
      empresa: {
        title: 'Empresa',
        valuePrepareFunction: (empresa) => {
          // I chose to display nombre
          return empresa.nombre;
        },
        filterFunction: (empresa?: any, search?: string) => {
          if (search.length > 0) {
            // Filter by empresa.nombre
            return empresa.nombre.match(search);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanksssss, that's what i needed, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of the empresa names properties, you can map the user array to be transformed to just the name of empresa. 
Here is how you can do it:

```
this.mainService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);

  const empresaNamesList = res.map(user => user.empresa.nombre);

  ...
}
```

Comment: I'v tried it, but i need to not show empresa as object, but a property of it, do you understand me?

Comment: yes, I understand what you want, just check out this code, I have maped to the exact property you want to show <name> `res.map(user => user.empresa.nombre);`

Comment: It brings me the empresa name, but i don't need only the name, but the rest of the res data. The problem is with the LocalSourceData, it assigns automatically the data to my table, so in the column of empresa i get [Object object], but i need the names, you get me?

Comment: The up comment marked worked for me, thanks for the help!